# counter для нескольких строк

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код:

```js
var tr = $('.row'),
    sum = tr.find('.sum'),
    startSum = parseInt(sum.text());


$('.btn-number').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    var 
    $this = $(this),
    fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field'),
    type      = $(this).attr('data-type'),
    input = $("input[name='"+fieldName+"']"),
    currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
  
  
    if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
        if(type == 'minus') {
            
            if(currentVal > input.attr('min')) {
                input.val(currentVal - 1).change();
              
              var counter = input.val();
              sum.html(counter*startSum);
              console.log();
            } 
            if(parseInt(input.val()) == input.attr('min')) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }

        } else if(type == 'plus') {

            if(currentVal < input.attr('max')) {
                input.val(currentVal + 1).change();
              
              var counter = input.val();
              sum.html(counter*startSum);
              console.log();
            }
            if(parseInt(input.val()) == input.attr('max')) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            }

        }
    } else {
        input.val(0);
    }
});
$('.input-number').focusin(function(){
   $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val());
  
   var counter = $(this).val();
      sum.text(counter*startSum);
});
$('.input-number').change(function() {
    
    minValue =  parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
    maxValue =  parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
    valueCurrent = parseInt($(this).val());
    
    name = $(this).attr('name');
    if(valueCurrent >= minValue) {
        $(".btn-number[data-type='minus'][data-field='"+name+"']").removeAttr('disabled');
      
      var counter = $(this).val();
      sum.text(counter*startSum);
    } else {
        alert('Sorry, the minimum value was reached');
        $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
      
    }
    if(valueCurrent <= maxValue) {
        $(".btn-number[data-type='plus'][data-field='"+name+"']").removeAttr('disabled');
      
      var counter = $(this).val();
      sum.text(counter*startSum);
    } else {
        alert('Sorry, the maximum value was reached');
        $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));
      
    }
    
    
});
$(".input-number").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
            (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) || 
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
                 // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

```css
button,
input,
.sum{
  padding: .5rem;
}

.sum {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="calc">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">- </button>  
      <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">  
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="sum">10</div>
  </div>
  
  
   <div class="row">
    <div class="calc">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">- </button>  
      <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">  
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>
    </div>
    <div class="sum">12</div>
  </div>
```

Если один `row`, то все работает отлично, а если несколько - не понимаю как сделать, чтобы правильно работало.

Для каждого поля `row` при увеличении\уменьшении counter должна и сумма увеличиваться\уменьшаться соответственно.

Как поправить код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
var tr,
  sum,
  startSum;


$('.btn-number').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  sum = $(tr).find(".sum");
  startSum = parseInt($(tr).find(".sum").data("num"));
  var
    fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field'),
    type = $(this).attr('data-type'),
    input = $(tr).find("input"),
    currentVal = parseInt(input.val());


  if (!isNaN(currentVal)) {
    if (type == 'minus') {

      if (currentVal > input.attr('min')) {
        input.val(currentVal - 1).change();

        var counter = input.val();
        sum.html(counter * startSum);
      }
      if (parseInt(input.val()) == input.attr('min')) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
      }

    } else if (type == 'plus') {

      if (currentVal < input.attr('max')) {
        input.val(currentVal + 1).change();

        var counter = input.val();
        sum.html(counter * startSum);

      }
      if (parseInt(input.val()) == input.attr('max')) {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
      }

    }
  } else {
    input.val(0);
  }
});
$('.input-number').focusin(function() {
  $(this).data('oldValue', $(this).val());

  var counter = $(this).val();
  sum.text(counter * startSum);
});
$('.input-number').change(function() {

  minValue = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
  maxValue = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
  valueCurrent = parseInt($(this).val());

  name = $(this).attr('name');
  if (valueCurrent >= minValue) {
    $(".btn-number[data-type='minus'][data-field='" + name + "']").removeAttr('disabled');

    var counter = $(this).val();
    sum.text(counter * startSum);
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, the minimum value was reached');
    $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));

  }
  if (valueCurrent <= maxValue) {
    $(".btn-number[data-type='plus'][data-field='" + name + "']").removeAttr('disabled');

    var counter = $(this).val();
    sum.text(counter * startSum);
  } else {
    alert('Sorry, the maximum value was reached');
    $(this).val($(this).data('oldValue'));

  }


});
$(".input-number").keydown(function(e) {
  // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
  if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 190]) !== -1 ||
    // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
    // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
    // let it happen, don't do anything
    return;
  }
  // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
  if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
button,
input,
.sum {
  padding: .5rem;
}
.sum {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="calc">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="sum" data-num="12">12</div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="calc">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="sum" data-num="13">13</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="calc">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="sum" data-num="14">14</div>
</div>
```

**UPD:**

```js
$('.btn-number').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent(),
    btn = $(this),
    sum = $(tr).find(".sum"),
    startSum = parseInt($(tr).find(".sum").data("num")),
    input = $(tr).find("input");
  if (isNaN(parseInt(sum.text()))) {
    input.val(0);
  } else {
    foo(btn, input, sum, startSum);
  }
});

function foo(btn, input, sum, startSum) {
  var minValue = parseInt(input.attr('min'));
  var maxValue = parseInt(input.attr('max'));
  var counter = btn.data("type") == "minus" ? parseInt(input.val()) - 1 : parseInt(input.val()) + 1;
  if (counter < minValue) {
    $(btn).prop('disabled', true);
    alert('Sorry, the minimum value was reached');
  } else if (counter > maxValue) {
    $(btn).prop('disabled', true);
    alert('Sorry, the maximum value was reached');
  } else {
    $(".btn").prop('disabled', false);
    $(btn).removeAttr('disabled');
    input.val(counter);
    sum.text(parseInt(counter) * parseInt(startSum));
  }
}
```

```css
button,
input,
.sum {
  padding: .5rem;
}
.sum {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="calc">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="sum" data-num="12">12</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="calc">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" disabled="disabled" data-type="minus" data-field="quant[1]">-</button>
    <input type="text" name="quant[1]" class="form-control input-number" value="1" min="1" max="10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-number" data-type="plus" data-field="quant[1]">+</button>
  </div>
  <div class="sum" data-num="13">13</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Упс, не работает если у второго, к примеру, сумма не 12,  а 10

Comment: @Elena поправил.... к `sum` добавил `data`...

Comment: Да и я так решила, думала какое-то есть более универсальное решение и простое (не хотелось еще и дата атрибут добавлять), но видимо нет (

Comment: @Elena - заклинаю Вас, не назначайте глобальную переменную в одном обработчике, чтобы потом использовать ее в другом! "Вы погубите себя, сын мой!" А. Дюма

Comment: @C.Raf.T - Вы тоже не назначайте!

Comment: @Igor, я других способов не знаю )))) Можете показать как лучше сделать, буду благодарна)

Comment: @Igor полностью согласен.. пытался не сломать то, что уже было. Добавил оптимальнее...))

Comment: @Elena обновил. думаю так лучше будет...))

Comment: @C.Raf.T, спасибо!